# Datepicker is not a function after ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, laravel, lumen

I'm writing simple search engine in Lumen framework.

I have a list of status for example. The user can get one of status from the list and after click search button then in the page, I need to load data with chosen status.

One of the element is datepicker. And this datepicker work great when I refresh the page or go to the page by `GET` method. But I have a problem when I go on the page by POST method from my click "SEARCH". There is some code from my view where I get status from the list and pass to my controller action:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {
        var clientId = null;
        var status = null;

        $("[name='deadline']").datepicker(); //there I have this error comunicat

        $('#clients').on('change', function () {
            clientId = $(this).val();

        });

        $('#statuses').on('change', function () {
            status = $(this).val();
        });

        $('#searchForPremium').on('click', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '/admin/clients/premium',
                data: {client_id: clientId, status: status},
                success: function (data) {

                    $('body').empty().html(data);

                    $('#clients').val(clientId);
                    $('#statuses').val(status);
                }
            });
        })
    });
</script>
```

And there is controlelr action:

```
public function clientsPremium()
    {

        $premiumTexts = NULL;

        $premiumClients = \App\Text::getPremiumClients();
        $premiumTexts = \App\Text::getPremiumTexts();
        $statuses = \App\Text::getStatus();

        if (Request::isMethod('get')) {
            $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(deadline), deadline'), 'ASC');
            $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->get();
            return view('admin.clients-premium', ['statuses' => $statuses, 'clients' => $premiumClients, 'texts' => $premiumTexts]);
        }
        if (Request::isMethod('post')) {
            $clientID = Request::get('client_id');
            $statusName = Request::get('status');

            if ($clientID != NULL) {
                $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->where('text.client_id', $clientID);
            }

            if ($statusName != NULL) {
                $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->where('text.status', $statusName);
            }

            $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->orderBy(DB::raw('ISNULL(deadline), deadline'), 'ASC');
            $premiumTexts = $premiumTexts->get();

            return response()->json(view('admin.clients-premium', ['statuses' => $statuses, 'clients' => $premiumClients, 'texts' => $premiumTexts])->render());
        }

    }
```

Then I have error "Uncaught TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function...". I cant understand how it is work and why I got this message. It appear only when I click to search button.
It is `$('body').empty().html(data);` or my controller action:

```
 return response()->json(view('admin.clients-premium', ['copywriters' => $copywriters, 'statuses' => $statuses, 'positioners' => $positioners, 'clients' => $premiumClients, 'texts' => $premiumTexts, 'allowedTemplates' => $allowedTemplates, 'section' => 'clients.premium'])->render());
```

I tried to use $.noConflict(); but there is no effect for me. Can anyone look at my code and try to help me what should I change? I think my return "response()->json(view..." reload all page and get my jquery-ui multiple time. But I can wrong. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 0):

Reinitialize it after you change content from ajax response.

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '/admin/clients/premium',
    data: {client_id: clientId, status: status},
    success: function (data) {

        $('body').empty().html(data);
        $("[name='deadline']").datepicker();     
        $('#clients').val(clientId);
        $('#statuses').val(status);
    }
});
```

Comment: oh but its call error on my script in first occurence of view(in place which I show in example  $("[name='deadline']").datepicker(); ), not in my ajax method

Comment: this might be due to the order you have added these scripts . datepicker JS must be included before this script

Answer (score 0):

After ajax success destroy the datepicker and reinitialize it as below:

```
$('body').empty().html(data);
$("[name='deadline']").datepicker("destroy");
$("[name='deadline']").datepicker();
```

Comment: thanks for answer but there is problem in other place. I have error in my <script> I showed this in my code example. Now it works good after click button "search" there I have loaded all my data but after that i have error in my first occurrence of "datepicker"(please look at code in my view in script section)

Comment: ok but then I need to remove  $("[name='deadline']").datepicker(); from script and used it only after ajax request. But I need to have datapicker before ajax too. There is problem with loading all scripts I think

Answer (score 0):

you clear entire body so may be possible you include js css in body so please add  and remove this div instead of entire body and if you add dynamic datepicker to any text box please use

```
  $("[name='deadline']").datepicker(); on ajax response .
```

Comment: so I shouldnt             return response()->json(view('admin.clients-premium', ['copywriters' => $copywriters...])->render()); and return only json to div? I think about this earlier but I havent idea how can I get this

Comment: instead of replace entire body please add your code in one div inside <body> and replace that div contain

Comment: can You explain me how can I include my data from request to view withoud loading all page? I think this is good way to reach this but I tried a lot of combinations for example mreturn only json data (without render, view etc) and only complete the view with new data from query without load all page scripts etc

Comment: Thanks for answer I understand this. But I dont know how should look my return from controller after ajax.  return response()->json(view(... I need to return json data only or what? How should looked my return ?

Comment: you have to create partition for code . sy e.g create one header file one container file and one footer file . when you redirect to your view please call header file , contain (your current view file) , footer file in one single file . header or footer file include all css and js . please read "contain" , "include" , 'yeild' , "extend" in laravel that will solve your problem . and you achive your desire output . Hope this will help you